# Can't get location on Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 & Note

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, android-location

I use this code to get the location:

```
final LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        final Criteria locationCritera = new Criteria();
        locationCritera.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
        locationCritera.setAltitudeRequired(false);
        locationCritera.setBearingRequired(false);
        locationCritera.setCostAllowed(true);
        locationCritera.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);

        final String providerName = locationManager.getBestProvider(locationCritera, true);

        if (providerName != null && locationManager.isProviderEnabled(providerName)) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(providerName, 20000, 100, this);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "GPS turned off!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            final Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Both ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permissions are defined in manifest.

Both network & GPS are turned on, but I'm getting only onProviderEnabled called with param "network" (once). But the same code works fine on 4.0 emulator & Onda 4.1 Tab.
Why?

Comment: In my experience some devices are deadly slow to receive GPS responses sometimes. Indoor doesn't help as well.

Comment: I have the same problem on Galaxy Tab 2. I used getLocationManager().getLastKnownLocation(provider) to at least show something to the user.

Answer (score 1):

I have a GPS example. Maybe you can use it as reference:
Example is [here](https://code.google.com/p/wifi-map-with-nokia-here-api/source/browse/src/com/buptcoder/wifimap/location/Locator.java):